# Why mvn android:lint skips sub modules?

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

Why does android:lint only scans my Aggregator Project for Lint warnings and skips the "APP" Module ?

In the POM of the APP Module i defined:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>lint</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>lint</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android.platform}</platform>
                </sdk>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>

                <sign>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </sign>
                <lint>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </lint>

                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                <zipalign>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</inputApk>
                    <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-aligned.apk</outputApk>
                </zipalign>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think we have implemented it to work in a multi module build this way. However you can just configure the plugin in the aggregator and the execution in the apk project and it will work.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Thats how Maven plugins are configured/used in general.